# Mule ESB Bean property 'enableNotifications' is not writable

Tags: properties, mule, javabeans, esb

I am working with Mule ESB 3.8.2 and I am receiving this error where I am compliling outside of Anypoint Studio.
Bean property 'enableNotifications' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
Someone has a suggest what could be?

Answer (score 0):

After some hours working on this issue I found the solution.
The file pom.xml we must have on plugin

```
<inclusion>
                        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
                    </inclusion>
```

and the dependencies must be the version of mule that we're working on it.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>`enter code here`
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I hope this could be helpfull for someone.